# WORKDIR as VOLUME

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my dockerfile, I have my `WORKDIR` and I want to have it as a `VOLUME`, so that on the host I have a directory in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` where is the same content as in the `WORKDIR`.
How do I use the `VOLUME` Dockerfile command for this?

Comment: Why do you specifically want a volume?  Can you share the content you have already?  I would recommend avoiding the Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive in most cases, and be wary of the Docker automatic named volume setup (if the image content changes, or you use a bind mount instead of a named volume, or you run on Kubernetes, the Docker automatic setup will not happen).

Comment: I want to have it so that I see the files in WORKDIR, because they are pulled from GitHub and it's not really reliable so I want to see if it updated.

Comment: You don't need a volume for that (and you shouldn't generally poke around in `/var/lib/docker`).  If you `docker run --rm -it yourimage bash` (assuming the image doesn't have a broken `ENTRYPOINT`) you will get an interactive shell in a container based on the image, and you can look at whatever you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can mount a volume over the `WORKDIR` that you were using when building your image, the volume isn't available at build time. Volumes are only available for a container, not while building an image.

You can `COPY` files into the image to represent the content that will exist in the volume once a container is running, and use those temporary files to complete the building of the image. However, those exact files would be inaccessible once a volume is mounted in that location.

To have a directory from the host machine mounted inside a container, you would pass a `-v` parameter (you can do multiple `-v` params for different directories or for individual files) to the `docker run` command that starts the container:

```sh
docker run -v /var/lib/docker/volumes:/full/path/inside/container your_image_name
```